# In search of an important shloka from Anushasana Parva of Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, shloka, stotra, vishnu-sahasranama

I am in search of an important shloka which is a part of Mahabharata (13th chapter, Anushasana Parva) after Vishnu Sahasranamam and the shloka is about praising rishis, munis, raja rishis, etc., to get wealth, health, success etc.

For reference, please see the link, http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13 and I need the shloka in English but not the translation.

The shloka starts with:

> Namo Vasishtaaya Maha vrataaya

Comment: may be this will help you https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/tag/anushasana-parva/

Comment: you can download anushana parva english translation here http://www.southasiaarchive.com/Content/sarf.100105/218842

Comment: Thanks for the comment sir, But i need the sanskrit sloka in english, but not the translation.  I got the translation before in sacred-text.com.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for these set of verses from [Anuśāsana Parva](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_13_u.htm). These appear to be from the [Southern Recension of Mahābhārata](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-13-itx.html) (13.255) and they didn't make it to the Critical Edition of Mahābhārata.

> 13,135.026d@018_0019    **namo vasiṣṭhāya mahāvratāya** 
>   13,135.026d@018_0020    parāśaraṃ vedanidhiṃ praṇamya 
>   13,135.026d@018_0021    namo 'stv anantāya mahoragāya 
>   13,135.026d@018_0022    namo 'stu siddhebhya ihākṣayebhyaḥ 
>   13,135.026d@018_0023    namo 'stv ṛṣibhyaḥ paramaṃ pareṣāṃ 
>   13,135.026d@018_0024    deveṣu devaṃ varadaṃ varāṇām 
>   13,135.026d@018_0025    sahasraśīrṣāya namaḥ śivāya 
>   13,135.026d@018_0026    sahasranāmāya janārdanāya

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sloka by Bhishma,

> Namo vashistaya mahantaya,
>   Parasara vedanidhi namaste !
>   Namostvanantaya mahoragaya,
>   Namosthu siddhebya ihakshebhya: !!
>
> Namostvrishibya paramam paresham
>   Deveshu devam varadam varaanaam !
>
> Sahasraseershaye namah sivaaya
>   Sahasranamaya Janardhanaya!!

Hope this is what you were looking for.